# How to center a div and keep the alignment to its nested floating divs?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have *`wrapper`* like `div` which contains two nested divs. I need them to be centered and I will add content (inputs) dynamically and I need one two be placed at the left and the other on the right side.

I tried:

```
<div id="matriz">dsg
    <div id="A">ds</div>
    <div id="b">dsa</div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
#matriz {

    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#A {

    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#b {

    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

However the inner divs are then not displayed centered but on the left and right extreme, there's an empty centered space.

I know `float: left` and `float: right` is making this. But how would I make it?

### I need all divs to be centered all along the screen (`viewport`?)

### Also, the nested divs should be placed together, with no empty centering spaces between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `float` for `#A` and `#b` will make you `div`s centered in the wrapper. What you  can do to align the two div always next to each other is set `max-width` for the two `div`s inside the `wrapper div`.

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/Dg8f3/2/)**, might help you

HTML:

```
<div id="matriz">
    <div id="top">Top content</div>
    <div id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
    <div id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #matriz {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:0;
}

#top{
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    font-size:16px;
}

#left {
    background-color:yellow;
    max-width:50%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:16px;
}

#right {
    max-width:50%;
    background-color:green;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Comment: What about whole divs to be centered along screen.

Comment: Which whole div? You mean the wrapper?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The wrapper. See my edit at last of post

Comment: Right now the wrapper is 100% `width`. If you give a fixed width and `margin: 0 auto` it would be centered. Also the inner divs are set with width auto. So its width expands to max 50% depending on the content. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/39james/Dg8f3/3/

Comment: I know my question would sound quite demanding, but what about reponsive? :p So far, it helped me out, Thanks!

Comment: Try re-sizing the fiddle in my answer and fiddle in my comment, you can see it is responsive because i have used % widths.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hack `display: table-cell` for these 3 elements.

```
#matriz {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}

#A{
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
}

#b{
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
}
```

[Fiddle :: full code](http://jsfiddle.net/sxJRc/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://jsfiddle.net/JP5Eu/

HTML:

```
<div id="matriz" class="">
    <div id="top">top</div>
    <div id="a">left</div>
    <div id="b">right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#matriz {
    position:absolute;

    width:100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background:red;
}


#a {
    width:50%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#b {
     width:50%;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different option.

http://jsfiddle.net/DrewGoldsberry/JP5Eu/1/

```
    <div id="matriz" class="">
<div id="CenteredTag">
<div id="a">left</div>
<div id="b">right</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

you can put the two tags inside of a container and set a max width. then center that tag.